# how can i calculate the average length of the strings entered

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my python homework assignment, The program asks the user for three strings and prints the average length of the strings entered

My code:

```
name1 = input ("enter first string: ")
name2 = input ("enter second string: ")
name3 = input ("enter third string: ")

total_strings = (name1.split()) + (name2.split()) + (name3.split()) 

average =( len(name1) + len(name2) + len(name3) )/len(total_strings)

print("the average length is: " + str(average))
```

---

So when I try it out the math gets a bit wierd.

input:

> a ajhs jah sjajsh jahs jah jah jsh as
>
> ajs jahjah sjhajsh jahs jah sjah jsh ajs
>
> ajs ajhs jah sjahs jah sjah sjah jsh ajhs jah s

===== Test failed here=====

> enter first string: enter second string: enter third string: the
>   average length is: 4.428571428571429

---

expected output:

---

> enter first string: enter second string: enter third string: the
>   average length is: 41.33

Comment: I think you're over complicating the issue by using `split()`.  Something like `lens = [len(name1), len(name2), len(name3)]; average = sum(lens)/len(lens)` should work just fine.

Comment: There's a library function for that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean

Comment: wow looks like i just over complicated my answer. Masque good seemed to work just pefect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` is creating a list of the words in a string; it is not what you want.

to take the average, you must sum the lengths of the strings, and divide by the number of strings:

```
name1 = input("enter first string: ")
name2 = input("enter second string: ")
name3 = input("enter third string: ")

average = (len(name1) + len(name2) + len(name3)) / 3

print("the average length is: " + str(average))
```

Comment: one last question how can I make the value of average into a 2 decimal floating point as in the expected output.

Comment: `round(1.12345, 2)` , will round the given number to the number of decimals specified.

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly in python 2.7.

```
name1 = raw_input("enter first string: ")
name2 = raw_input("enter second string: ")
name3 = raw_input("enter third string: ")

average = (len(name1) + len(name2) + len(name3)) / 3

print("the average length is: " + str(average))
```

Hope it helps.